# I want to get value of selected row of gridview for specific column and use that value for crosspage posting - how to implement this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, cross-page-posting

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    string tenderno = row.Cells[1].Text;
    Response.Redirect("crossPage.aspx?tenderno=" + tenderno);
}
```

I am using autogenerated column for gridview. I am unable to fetch value on another page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
     AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:GridView>
```

Used this but `SelectedIndexChanged()` is not working.

Comment: Perhaps storing the value in session or QueryString would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="<%#"crossPage.aspx?tenderno="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"tender_no") %>">Select</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I used this, it worked for me but it shows value on url. Is there any other way to work same without showing value in url.

Comment: u can use button rather instead of  anchor link

Answer (score 0):

you can use button for do not show link.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <button type="button" onclick='location.href="<%#"crossPage.aspx?tenderno="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"tender_no") %>"'> Select</button>
</ItemTemplate>
```